# Build error when fetching page data: Cannot read property 'b' of undefined

Tags: next.js

I am getting a typeerror when trying to build my next js project, 'cannot read property b of undefined' (nowhere in the app do I try to access a property 'b' so it doesnt say much).

It seems to go away when I comment out all children in inside of the page component but not one specific child causing the issue e.g:

```
// error
function MyPage({dataFromGetStaticProps}:dataType)){

  return (
    <Div>
      <Comp1 />
      <Comp2 />
      <Comp3 />
    </Div>
  )

}

// error when individually commenting out a child 
function MyPage({dataFromGetStaticProps}:dataType)){

  return (
    <Div>
      <Comp2 />
      <Comp3 />
    </Div>
  )

}

// works
function MyPage({dataFromGetStaticProps}:dataType)){

  return (
    <Div>
     
    </Div>
  )

}
```

I have tried running --debug with the build but it shoes nothing and the app runs fine when running next dev.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

I have:

- Checked my imports
- Checked the data being received by the function is valid and of expected type
- Checked there is no errors on on the api where the data is coming from  i.e that my production server serving data to the app is working fine (even switched it to the local one but still no luck)
- Running yarn build with the NODE_ENV = development causes all of the errors to disappear

Comment: Are you certain you cannot pinpoint which component is causing the issue? One of them must be causing it. Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @juliomalves Hey thanks for responding, I have been trying to all day and found that it occurs when I duplicate a particular function (the same one) in more than one place in my code. So in two pages im using the same function component and disabling either one of them fixes the issue, The only thing the function does is return a reference to another component. e.g `function thatCausesError(){return [value, ComponentA]}` where component A has been imported into this function... Its weird...

Comment: And unfortunately i cant replicate it without duplicating my entire project as no other function is causing this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a circular dependency, You can add this plugin to the next config file here and see if you have any

```
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.plugins.push(
            new CircularDependencyPlugin({
                allowAsyncCycles: false,
                cwd: process.cwd(),
            })
        );
        return config;
    },
```